# How do I access as value inside of Angular select

Tags: angularjs

Is there a good way to access userName inside of scope while keeping the id in the context of:

```
<select id="pendingInvites" class="selectAlternateEvens" style="width: 85%; height: 300px;" ng-options="invite.id as invite.userName for invite in PendingInviteList"
                                multiple value=""
                                ng-model="user.pendingUserName"></select>
```

The ng-model currently resolves to the id, user.pendingUserName.userName doesn't work either.  I can do a look up against PendingInviteList, or I can use invite.userName in place of the id, but can I access it via the code above?

Comment: what do you need in the ng-model of the select ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store the user obj, change

```
ng-options="invite.id as invite.userName for invite in PendingInviteList"
```

to 
    ng-options="invite as invite.userName for invite in PendingInviteList"
    ng-model="user"

if you whant only name and not the id

```
ng-options="invite.userName as invite.userName for invite in 
PendingInviteList"
ng-model="user.pendingUserName"
```